# Component Object Model (COM): Where does IMalloc::Alloc allocate memory?

Tags: c++, winapi, com, dynamic-memory-allocation

Reading into COM for some legacy project. So far, my understanding is that COM is just a binary specification, and that all implementing components (client and server) must stick to this specification. As long as we are handling COM interfaces with methods receiving and returning only simple value types, everything makes perfect sense to me.

However, there is also the possibility to send **pointers** to entire objects/variants (containing e.g. a `SAFEARRAY`) from/to COM objects, and I wonder where the memory of these param objects is allocated. I read that it is memory owned by windows, and that we should not tamper with it except through COM methods.
Then I stumbled upon the `IMalloc` COM interface with its `Alloc` method, that seems to allocate a junk of memory in a COM-aware fashion, which perfectly completed the confusion.

In order to not interfere with the heap structure maintained by e.g. C++ (assuming we are writing the COM server in C++), where exactly does `IMalloc` allocate the memory?

Comment: Why do you care? If you allocate a SAFEARRAY, you will (must) use the corresponding APIs.

Comment: COM is programming language independent and can be used with a wide variety of languages so it is not tied to the C++ Runtime. [IMalloc interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678425(v=vs.85).aspx) provides some details about the interface.

Comment: @SimonMourier, I care because I want to **understand**, not just use.

Comment: Knowing *where* that memory gets allocated from is not a vital part of understanding COM. What would you do differently, if you knew that it were allocated from a system-provided private heap as opposed to the process' default heap?

Comment: My impression of your post is that your confusion comes from the boundary between the application using COM, the client, and the server which is written using the COM specification. COM does what is called marshalling of data that is passed through the interface between the client and the server. How this is done and if copying of data is done depends on whether it is an InProcess server or not. An InProcess server shares the address space of the application.

Comment: @RichardChambers: Whether data is copied depends on the marshaller used. A custom marshaller could use shared memory to transfer data across process boundaries, without provoking a copy. Likewise, an InProcess server may still require to have data copied, if the interface pointer crosses an apartment boundary. Sharing the same address space has no bearing. It's the apartment boundaries that matter in COM.

Comment: That's a meaningless question, based off of a false premise. No matter the number of allocators using the same heap, the allocator implementations will not ever interfere with each other. Would you be just as worried about integer array allocations and character array allocations interfering with each other when using the same heap?

Comment: @IInspectable The false premise was that I thought C++‘s `malloc` manages its own heap in virtual memory directly, using its own algorithm and data structures. Now I know better and I thank everyone who pointed this out in a constructive and respectful manner.

Comment: I understand that you finally agree, that this question is meaningless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windows used to create a dedicated heap for COM allocations, CoTaskMemAlloc() allocated it from it directly. That however was dropped at Win8, it now allocates from the default process heap, GetProcessHeap() returns it. The Microsoft CRT at VS2012 was changed as well, used to have its own heap but now also uses the default process heap.

The exact reason these changes were made is murky to me, I never saw a good explanation for it.  But is not unlikely to have something to do with WinRT (aka UWP, aka Windows Store, aka Modern UI). Heavily COM-powered under the hood but with a pretty tight language runtime integration provided by the language projection.  Or just to bypass the constant trouble these different heaps used to cause.  Especially the CRT heap was a DLL Hell nightmare with programs failing miserably when they were rebuilt on a new VS version but still used an old DLL.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! I was not aware that there are multiple different heaps in a process' memory. However, in Win8, how does it prevent collision of memory in the default heap? How does one language know whether or not some chunk of memory is actually free and not used by COM?

Comment: Well, that is exactly the problem.  The nasty failure mode is a module using one heap to allocate and another module using a different heap to release.  Otherwise the reason COM had a dedicated heap, with the rule that you always had to use the COM-provided allocators to stay out of trouble.  Particularly in WinRT that got to be murky since the language runtime and the OS plumbing got a lot more interwoven.  Pretty decent explanation, I can't be completely sure.

Comment: @MightyNicM the way the heap works is that a memory allocation is requested and then it is owned by what ever requested it. If you didn't request it then you don't own it. A client may provide a pointer to an area of memory to a COM server however this is not a transfer of ownership, the client still owns the memory. As far as any particular thread within a process knows, it is the only thread doing memory allocation and what other threads are doing is not really its concern. Problems can happen when ownership is transferred.

Comment: So I know that `malloc` uses a specific memory-layout to mark segments that are in use, and those that are still free. It doesn't have access to the entire heap upfront, as it needs to request chunks from windows to work on. So do you mean that windows manages its own chunks of memory for each component, such that C++ malloc is just one of those components, requesting its chunks from windows?

Comment: malloc() does not do anything special in the Microsoft CRT, it directly calls HeapAlloc().  Which requires the heap handle, the topic of this Q+A.  It is the job of the built-in heap manager to allocate VM.

Comment: If you had an App and a DLL both statically linked to the CRT you could get into a right mess with memory management.  .Post this change you can malloc/free without corrupting the CRT heap as it's now the process WIN32API heap.

Comment: It is not a complete get-out-jail card.  The CRT still has a lot of other shared state, basic stuff like errno, stdout, etc.  Memory corruption is not the first problem, starting with Vista calling free() with the wrong heap handle trips an AVE, XP used to silently ignore it and produced a leak.  Notable is that it does get to be a lot harder to test code that also needs to run on Win7.

Comment: @MightyNic Thing is (and this is why I posted as I did) the COM memory model was specifically designed to avoid all these problems, and that important detail could easily get lost here.

Comment: I learned about multiple heaps per process, and heap handles, as well as the fact that `malloc` in the CRT basically doesn't use a private heap (as a huge chunk in the actual process heap) and does allocation within that, but rather directly uses the process heap managed by windows. And this is also why COM can safely allocate its memory, because it goes via the same windows API functions as `malloc`. Correct?

Comment: @MightyNicM: Incorrect. The COM allocator can safely allocate memory, because it is designed to be safe, when used with the respective `IMalloc::Free` function. The implementation details do not matter. It could use the process' default heap, its own heap, some system heap, or some other memory altogether.

Comment: @IInspectable: So what you are saying is: Because we have defined A, A follows. The purpose of this question is to get an understanding how something could work, in principle. I am indeed interested in the implemenation details here, as this deepens my understanding. If I ever only rely on the specification of something, I wouldn't learn much, nor would I be able to design systems and interfaces myself. I don't consider someone a good programmer if he can use a `sort` method, but never heard of any particular sort algorithm.

Comment: @MightyNicM: The whole design goal of COM is to split interface and implementation. If you want to understand COM, you'll have to stop thinking in implementation details, and concentrate on interfaces alongside their respective contracts.

Comment: IInspectable: If I want to use COM and understand it on its abstraction level, then yes. But that's not what I was asking for.

Comment: @MightyNicM: You keep asking for meaningless information. It's almost like saying that to understand C++ you need to know how any given implementation implements its allocators. Surely, different implementations implement their allocators differently. And COM's allocator implementations changed over time. So, again, why do you believe that knowing how Win95 implements `IMalloc::Alloc` would help you understand COM? Please be specific.

Comment: For me, the information I received was extremely valuable, as I learned something fundamental about memory management on Windows. I got pointers to relevant concepts (like heap handles) which allow me to search the web more focused. I encountered a principal problem through studying COM, and I was very specific about my question (as specific as I could have been given my prior knowledge on the subject). I am obviously less interested in how to use COM, and more in one aspect of its implementation that now helps me understand related issues outside COM, too.

Comment: You've got my blessing, this does matter when the code blows up.  You'd have to wonder a bit how many devs actually know that they need to re-test their app on Win7.  Albeit that this doesn't seem to go wrong as often as it could.

Comment: Please use your votes, this doesn't belong in my inbox.  Or his, I'd imagine.

Answer (score 3):

My answer to this question is: *I don't know and I don't care*.

What you *do* have to do though is to abide by the rules.  COM (and COM objects) are free to allocate memory in any way they choose and any assumption you might make about where or how they do it is dangerous and unnecessary.  Probably, in the end, it's ultimately allocated via `HeapAlloc()`, but it needn't be and even if it is you certainly don't know *which* heap.

Memory allocation by the client (via `CoTaskMemAlloc()`, say) when calling into a COM object is relatively rare.  It's more common for the COM object to allocate whatever memory it needs in order to parcel up the results of the call and then return you a pointer - often in the form of another COM object - that you can use for whatever you need to do next.  The API documentation for the method in question will tell you what to do when you are done with that pointer and that's all you ever need to know.  This exact mechanism varies by API, for example:

- For a COM object call `Release();` on that object (this is usually implied, rather than being called out explicitly in the docs).
- For a 'raw' pointer, the documentation might tell you to call or `CoTaskMemFree()` or maybe `IMalloc::Free()`.
- For a SAFEARRAY call `SafeArrayUnaccessData()` / `SafeArrayUnlock()` / `SafeArrayDestroy()`.
- Sometimes you need to call something a bit off-the wall, such as `SysFreeString()`.

Anyway - always - for any particular API, read the docs and you should be OK.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think my main point of confusion was that there can be multiple heaps per process, and that C's `malloc` basically just uses the WinAPI heap allocation functions, and doesn't do anything magic itself.

Comment: @MightyNic Yes, pretty much.  Hans's answer (and the comments above) contain more detail but at the end of the day, insofar as COM is concerned, you can just forget about it.  DLL hell, that's another thing, but COM neatly sidesteps all that.  Well, the memory management side of it, anyway.